Is there a DBpedia SPARQL endpoint for older versions, specifically the 2016.04 release?
I need to query an older version of DBpedia, specifically the 2016.04 release, for my project. The current SPARQL endpoint (https://dbpedia.org/sparql) provides access to the latest version, but I require data from the 2016.04 version.
Is there an online SPARQL endpoint available for older versions of DBpedia, or is there a method to access and query the 2016.04 release offline?
Any guidance on accessing older versions of DBpedia for SPARQL querying would be greatly appreciated.

you can always download older releases from their archive, for your request see here: https://downloads.dbpedia.org/2016-04/ - the /core folder should contain all (sub)datasets making up the release dump. And for recent release I would use the DBpedia databus

But among all that files what are the ones needed to have the full DBpedia 2016.04 ?
